# Configure AWS Cognito User Pool Advanced Security Features Account Takeover Risk Configuration via CLI

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-cli

Attempting to configure my Cognito user pool via the CLI

If I run

`aws cognito-idp set-risk-configuration --user-pool-id ap-southeast-2_123456789 --account-takeover-risk-configuration Actions={LowAction={Notify=false,EventAction=NO_ACTION},MediumAction={Notify=false,EventAction=NO_ACTION},HighAction={Notify=false,EventAction=NO_ACTION}}`

I just get the error

`Unknown options: Actions=MediumAction=Notify=false, Actions=MediumAction=EventAction=NO_ACTION, Actions=HighAction=Notify=false, Actions=HighAction=EventAction=NO_ACTION, Actions=LowAction=EventAction=NO_ACTION`

I have tried simplifying my request to just

`aws cognito-idp set-risk-configuration --user-pool-id ap-southeast-2_123456789 --account-takeover-risk-configuration Actions={HighAction={EventAction=NO_ACTION}}`

And I get the error

`Missing required parameter in AccountTakeoverRiskConfiguration.Actions.HighAction: "Notify"`

So I know I am on the right track, but then when I change my command to

`aws cognito-idp set-risk-configuration --user-pool-id ap-southeast-2_123456789 --account-takeover-risk-configuration Actions={HighAction={EventAction=NO_ACTION,Notify=false}}` to satisfy the missing param, I get `Unknown options: Actions={HighAction=Notify=false}`

What is the correct syntax for the Notify param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed by AWS support as a bug where the boolean is simply being dropped by the parser

Only fix is to use an external JSON file for the props.

`set-risk-configuration --user-pool-id ap-southeast-2_123456789 --account-takeover-risk-configuration file://riskconfig.json`

riskconfig.json

```
{
    "Actions": {
        "LowAction": {
            "Notify": false,
            "EventAction": "NO_ACTION"
        },
        "MediumAction": {
            "Notify": false,
            "EventAction": "NO_ACTION"
        },
        "HighAction": {
            "Notify": false,
            "EventAction": "NO_ACTION"
        }
    }
}
```